# What is it called when you seperate from a country

Tags: word-request

its crazy how we speak? i have hard times sometimes speaking!
Is it called seceding?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. @SamBC has kindly provided a good answer, but ideally you should provide much more detail with your questions, especially about the efforts you have made to find an answer yourself. https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Answer (score 5):

***Secession*** is the act of part of a group separating from the wider group, and the verb is ***to secede***. So if part of a country separates from the rest of a country, it has seceded, as a country can generally be considered a sort of group - albeit a group of territorial areas rather than a group of people.

If people, but not territory, separate from their country, that's something else. They might *renounce their nationality*, *emigrate*, or *defect*, all of which are distinct concepts (though someone who defects generally also emigrates).

Comment: I noticed you frequently use *albeit* in your answers. I am wondering whether it's just a personal preference. Or is the word preferable to *although* in certain cases? (Thank you)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Well, it's not interchangeable with *although*. You can't swap it one-for-one. Sometimes it can be swapped directly for *though*, but not always. It's been my experience that it's not an unusual word to use for English people with certain sorts of education.